# How can I send whatsapp message to new whatsapp authentication template?

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

I created and got approved the whatsapp authenthication template using the new format, ok, got approved.

[Sample template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pHK7.png)

But how can I send/use as a message this template? Different from others templates and I just need to send the same body replacing the parameters, I couldn´t find how I can send this one.

I already tried to send regular message as "123456 is your verification code. For your security, do not share this code." but didn´t work, it does not consider as using a template.

Can someone please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To send messages from templates created using the Content API or Content Editor, you will need two new fields in your API request. You will also need a Messaging Service.

```js
// Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install
// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages
      .create({
         contentSid: 'HXXXXXXXXX',
         from: 'MGXXXXXXXX',
         contentVariables: JSON.stringify({
           1: 'Name'
         }),
         to: 'whatsapp:+18551234567'
       })
      .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

[Docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/content/send-templates-created-with-the-content-editor)

Comment: Hi, thanks, but didn´t work. I created the service message, ok, but as you can see in the "sample template" link in my question, it´s an OTP whatsapp message, and since is authentication, I don´t know how should be sent the content variables for this one, I tried with the code number as sample, but still didn´t work. Can you help me please? Thanks.